# Voltage controlled oscillator with a MOSFET

Tags: vco, varactor

Is it a good idea to use a normal MOSFET as a varactor for a variable signal generator?

For example:

I have an IRFZ44N and the datasheets says it has an input capacitance of 1470 pF. Can I use that capacitance? Especially for much lower frequencies? I was thinking below 500 kHz.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a good idea but, who can say without your idea expressed schematically.

Comment: The datasheet says the TYPICAL capacitance is 1470.   They do not specify min or maximum possible values.

Answer (score 3):

It takes about 5 V to change the drain-gate capacitance by about 50 %.

A varactor in an oscillator is mostly used in RF (> 100 MHz) circuits; although nowadays there are invariably PLLs instead with a single fixed frequency oscillator.

For a 500 kHz VCO I'd suggest varying the resistor instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sure the capacitance varies with voltage so it could work .You could short gs and do Cds which will give less capacitance but the possibility of much higher voltage operation .Power mosfets do have gate resistance sometimes a few ohms this could have a big effect on Q .The drain source resistance is much lower so a smaller effect on Q is expected.It is possible to tune a LC power osc this way but the mosfets were large die area devices that cost too much last century .Such a scheme gave much more C than a daunting bank of varicap diodes.But the varicap diodes are better specified in terms of C .Powermosfets are not accurately specified for C so good for fun but careful in production .